# obtener el nombre de un parametro en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

buenas tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
def http1(response):

    respone.????
    ...
```

la llamo de la siguiente forma pasandole una función que también recibe un parámetro

```
http1(http2(parametro))
```

mi pregunta es como obtengo el nombre del parametro de la funcion http2 para que pueda trabajr con el en la funcion http1 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, "obtener el nombre del parámetro" no sirve de nada, "el nombre del parámetro" AKA "variable" no es más que eso, un nombre asociado a un objeto en memoria. Lo que necesitas no es el nombre del parámetro, sino una referencia al objeto pasado como argumento.

Tal y como lo planteas es imposible, `http2` recibe **la salida de `http1`**, a no ser que `http1` retorne alguna referencia a `response` no podrás acceder desde `http2`. Si este no es el caso:

- Hacer que `http1` retorne también una referencia a `response`:

  ```
  class Response:
      foo = 7

  def http1(response):
      response.foo += 3
      return "Hola", response

  def http2(arg):
      http1_resp, response = arg
      print(response.foo)

  response = Response()
  http2(http1(response))
  ```

  ---

  ```
  def http1(response):
      response[0] += 3
      return "Hola", response

  def http2(arg):
      http1_resp, response = arg
      print(response)

  http2(http1([7, 2]))
  ```
- Pasar a `http2` una referencia a la función y los argumentos a pasar a la función y ejecutarla dentro de `http2`:

  ```
  class Response:
      foo = 7

  def http1(response):
      response.foo += 3
      return "Hola"

  def http2(func, response):
      http1_resp = func(response)
      print(response)

  response = Response()
  http2(http1, response)
  ```

  ---

  ```
  def http1(response):
      response[0] += 3
      return "Hola", response

  def http2(func, response):
      http1_resp = func(response)
      print(response)

  http2(http1, [7, 2])
  ```

Comment: estoy usando programación estructurada no orientada a objetos

Comment: `respone.????` es la forma de referenciar un atributo, por eso uso la clase `Response` para emularlo... La idea es la misma sea lo que sea que le pases como argumento (en Python va a ser un objeto de una clase determinada de todas formas, todo son objetos desde un entero hasta una función), no necesitas Response para que los ejemplos funcionen, he añadido otros dos ejemplos usando una lista como argumento.